# is any way mapper use share data?

Tags: mapreduce, hashmap, share

I want my mapper use hash map for checking something. The hash map values is same for all mapper and each mapper load that individually and all memory is consumed by that. I want the hash map load one and all mapper use that.You do think any way for that? I know each mapper use difference JVM machine.
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

There is something called distributed cache. Even using distributed cache you will not be able to share memory(your hashmap) between two mapper jvm processes. 
But this distributed cache serves the purpose of distributing your small files like lookup files over all the nodes in the cluster. And again you have to construct your hashmap seperately for each of your mapper processes in a node.

Comment: I want to share memory between mappers JVM processes and distributed cache not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

define the hash map as static member variable in **Map Class
define `static boolean init_once = false`

overide Setup function, initilize hash map in setup (setup is called once in each task, but all maptask  share  can share the hash map )

define boolean init_once = false, in setup function

```
if(!init_once)
{
   init_once = true;
   //* you init code here
}
```

notes: it is not thread safe, if hadoop maptask is run in multi-thread mode, mutex should be used to make sure the operation is itom

Comment: I do that but each map load hash map.

Comment: I see, setup is called in each task.

Comment: I hear if hash map define as static is run per task tracker but not test.

Comment: @vahid, I am not sure about that , I update my answer about the init part , which I have tried

Answer (score 0):

@vahid  Map/Reduce is explicitly not set up that way. What happens if one of the mappers fails and needs to be restarted?  Maybe you should look into something like MPI.  Small amounts of signaling info can be shared via counters - which are transmitted along with each heartbeat.

Comment: If one of Mappers failed will not any problem in my case. MPI is very exhausting and I don't like that. I force to reduce number of Mapper and each mapper used 1.5 GB of memory and instead finish in one day is finish on two days.